# Trying to make a random character generator but won't always get an answer

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a random character generator for D&D. So far I am able to make a decision on what class to pick based on the two largest stats but for some reason every now and then I get no answer. My code is fine as far as I can tell but I am a beginner in python. I would love to know why it won't always return answers and how to fix it.

```
data = [str,int,dex,con,wis,cha]

largest = None
second_largest = None

for a in data:
    if not largest or a > largest:
        if largest:
            second_largest = largest
        largest = a
if largest == wis and second_largest == cha or largest == cha and second_largest == str or largest == str and second_largest == cha or largest == str and second_largest == int:
 print ("PALADIN")

elif largest == str and second_largest == dex or largest == str and second_largest == con or largest == con and second_largest == str: 
 print ("BARBARIAN")

elif largest == str and second_largest == wis or largest == con and second_largest == wis or largest == wis and second_largest == str or largest == wis and second_largest == con:
 print ("CLERIC")

elif largest == int and second_largest == str or largest == int and second_largest == con or largest == con and second_largest == int or largest == wis and second_largest == int:
 print ("WIZARD")                     

elif largest == int and second_largest == dex or largest == dex and second_largest == int or largest == cha and second_largest == wis: 
 print ("ROGUE")

elif largest == int and second_largest == wis: 
 print ("DRUID")

elif largest == int and second_largest == cha or largest == con and second_largest == cha or largest == cha and second_largest == int: 
 print ("SORCERER")

elif largest == dex and second_largest == str: 
 print ("MONK")

elif largest == dex and second_largest == con or largest == con and second_largest == dex: 
 print ("FIGHTER")

elif largest == dex and second_largest == wis or largest == wis and second_largest == dex:
 print ("RANGER")

elif largest == dex and second_largest == cha: 
 print ("BARD")

elif largest == cha and second_largest == dex or largest == cha and second_largest == con:
 print ("WARLOCK")
```

Comment: It's hard to tell. Your code has several flaws. Can you identify one specific example of input that fails? Try to provide one example with input, obtained input (if any), and expected output. Furthermore, please give one specific example of values for the list `data`.

Comment: 1st: No else statement. 2nd: to choose 2 elements out of 6 there are 15 possible outcomes. Respecting the order makes 30 different combinations (largest and second largest being not equal)

Comment: In case anyone was wondering whether all the possibilities were covered (they are): https://gist.github.com/minitech/97723bb4ae8d19b3b6b320a4995afb91

Comment: I think I did have a potential response for all 30 possibilities. My problem is that every now and then when the code is run it determines and displays the stats, then I get no response for what class should be chosen. The response is just blank then moves on. It gives a response around 7/10 times, but I don't know why it won't work all the time.

Comment: Basic debugging: `print` the `largest` and `second_largest` after selecting them.

Comment: Re-using standard identifiers like *str* and *int* can't be recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for getting the largest and second largest isn’t right:

```
largest = None
second_largest = None

for a in data:
    if not largest or a > largest:
        if largest:
            second_largest = largest
        largest = a
```

If the largest attribute appears before the second largest, `second_largest` won’t be filled in. A short and readable way would be just to use a sort, assuming efficiency isn’t that much of a concern:

```
largest, second_largest = sorted(data, reverse=True)[:2]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this now.

Answer (score 1):

If your largest element is the first, you will never get the second_largest assigned.
You can change it to:

```
entlargest = -float('inf')
second_largest = -float('inf')

for a in data:
    if a > second_largest:
        second_largest = a
        if second_largest > largest:
             largest, second_largest = second_largest, largest
```